# is there quick way to generate the markup control in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-interface, user-controls, code-generation

I want a method that does as follows:

GenerateMarkup(Label l); ==> output is
    '>asp:label runat="server" ID="label1"/<'
and I'm wondering if there's any of-the-shelf method instead of doing it my self.

Comment: you want to display markup on the web browser

Comment: no I'm generating, ascx.

Comment: Are your '>' and '<' backwards  after ==> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured no there's not any and I had to write it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there exists code that helps with this. Basically,  you're talking about compiling your input into some sort of output.

In your case, you're compiling *some input* into an .ASCX file (probably with a code-behind).

This code project covers dynamically generating ASP.NET pages and does a pretty good job of explaining the process.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xmlxsltransformer.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I meant an of-the-shelf solution that can generate the markup for a specific control.

Comment: Hi Bassel. I'll leave my answer as a reference, but can you please edit your question to be a little more clear? Thanks!